# How to read the specific fields from the XML payload, where this payload is coming again in the field of the main XML payload

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0, xslt-grouping

Need help to read the XML payload which is coming inside one of the field.

> ## Request Payload:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Code xmlns:ns0="http://example.com">
   <Header>
      <Field1>111</Field1>
      <Field2>text</Field2>
   </Header>
   <Trailer>
     &lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;
        <Field4>
            <Field5>
               <Field6>Age</Field6>
                 <Field7>Location</Field7>
               <Field6>Age</Field6>
                 <Field7>Location</Field7>
            </Field5>
        </Field4>
   </Trailer>
</Code>
```

> Above is the Request XML payload in which we have field called `<Trailer>`
> where we are again getting an XML payload. We need to fetch only the
> selected fields from the XML payload which is in the `<Trailer>` field
> and generate below Output.
>
> ## Expected Output Payload:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Code xmlns:ns0=http://example.com>
   <Header>
      <Field1>111</Field1>
      <Field2>text</Field2>
   </Header>
   <Field5>
        <Field6>Age</Field6>
            <Field7>Location</Field7>
         <Field6>Age</Field6>
             <Field7>Location</Field7>
    </Field5>
</Code>
```

I tried with below XSLT but I am unlucky to fetch the required fields from the `<Trailer>` field

> ## XSLT Code:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<Code>
 <xsl:copy-of select="//Header" />
 <xsl:value-of select="//Trailer" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>

</Code>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Where exactly are you getting EmployeeDetails in the Field5 element of you output?  Employee details is not in the input XML.  And it not being calculated in the XSLT.

Comment: Sorry @JohnErnst my bad. I have now corrected the field value

Comment: Please pick **one** of `xslt-1.0`, `xslt-2.0`, `xslt-3.0` tags, not all of them. And what does  this have to go with grouping??

Comment: Are you sure that is the actual XML input you are getting? It doesn't seem likely that  the XML declaration would be escaped, but the following elements would be not. Or that there would not be a root element wrapping them.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: Have corrected the Input and Output Payload. Apologies for that

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- Identity template. -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Trailer">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Field4/Field5"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply
XML structure hirerarchy is breaking as Field6 & Field7 is under Field5. and after the XSLT all Field5,6,7 are coming in the same hirerachy .

Also instead of defining Field5,6 & 7. is it possible that we only define Field5 and then all the fields which are under Field5 can automatically comeup with the same hirerachy ?

Comment: Your expected output XML is not well formed.  You have 2 closing tags for Field5.  Can you fix it so we know want you really want?

Comment: Now give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not entirely clear. The expected result can be produced using:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Trailer">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Field4/Field5"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply
XML structure hirerarchy is breaking as Field6 & Field7 is under Field5. and after the XSLT all Field5,6,7 are coming in the same hirerachy .

Also instead of defining Field5,6 & 7. is it possible that we only define Field5 and then all the fields which are under Field5 can automatically comeup with the same hirerachy ?

Comment: I have edited my answer to match your updated question.